# Question how to get value from map on map like this code

Tags: java, hashmap

i have source code like this

```
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

// Create a Map object called people


    Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> people = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Integer>>();

// Add keys and values (Name, (Sex,Age))
people.put("John", createMap("M",32));
people.put("Steve", createMap("M",30));
people.put("Angie", createMap("W",33));


    for (String i : people.keySet()) {
      System.out.println("key: " + i + " value: " + people.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

my question is i want to get name of people with have sex M with age more then 30 how to get that name and their age ?

regards,

Fuad

Comment: loop over the map and add the desired  one on a second map (or whatever data structure you need)

Comment: Is your code can compile success?

Comment: Despite your code does not compile, you should think about having another data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we change your code to compile like that:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> people = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Integer>>();

// Add keys and values (Name, (Sex,Age))
people.put("John", createMap("M",32));
people.put("Steve", createMap("M",30));
people.put("Angie", createMap("W",33));

...

private static Map<String, Integer> createMap(String key, Integer value) {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(key, value);
  return map;
}
```

You can then use your loop like that to filter for your people with the given condition:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : people.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().containsKey("M") && entry.getValue().get("M") > 30) {
    System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + people.get(entry.getKey()));
  }
}
```

But as mentioned, if you can, you should change your data structures for holding the people information. But as you set your code as given, the above would work and yield the result of `John` being male and older then 30.

Comment: If this helps you, you can accept is as an answer to your question.